# Improving performance by avoiding python for cycle when using counts of numpy unique

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, unique

I have two numpy arrays, `A` with shape `(N,3)` and B with shape `(N,)` and I generate from the vector A the vector with unique entries, e.g.:

```
A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],
              [4.,5.,6.],
              [1.,2.,3.],
              [7.,8.,9.]])

B = np.array([10.,33.,15.,17.])

AUnique, directInd, inverseInd, counts = np.unique(A, 
                                             return_index = True, 
                                             return_inverse = True, 
                                             return_counts = True, 
                                             axis = 0)
```

So that `AUnique` will be 
`array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])`

Then I obtain the simil-vector `B` associated to `AUnique`, and for each non-unique row in `A` I sum the associated values of `B` in this vector, that is:

```
BNew = B[directInd] 

# here BNew is [10., 33.,17]

for Id in np.asarray(counts>1).nonzero()[0]: 
  BNew[Id] = np.sum(B[inverseInd == Id])

# here BNew is [25., 33.,17]
```

The problem is that the for cycle gets extremely slow for large N vectors (millions or tens of millions rows), and I was wondering if there is a way to avoid cycling and/or to make the code much faster.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `np.bincount`

```
BNew = np.bincount(inverseInd, weights = B)
BNew

Out[]: array([25., 33., 17.])
```

Comment: make sure to mark as solved! there's a checkmark under the upvote button.